# Ruby version incompatibility when installing via bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version

I want to install ruby on rails app via bundler with:

```
bundle install
```

It gets me following error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0
```

However if i run **ruby -v** i get following output:

```
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

Comment: what is the version showing if you do `sudo ruby -v`

Comment: Are you using rvm?

Comment: Yes @M.Karim the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Ruby version is okay, I think the problem is with `bundle` command. You call bundle from your system preinstalled old Ruby. Run `which bundle` to locate it. I would recommend to switch to old Ruby, then uninstall `gem bundler`, then switch to new Ruby and reinstall `gem bundler`.

It's unclear which Ruby version manager you're using, so the basic command flow looks like this:

```
gem uninstall bundler # this command may require sudo
gem install bundler
```

Try switching Ruby versions inbetween commands, if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

what ruby manger do you use ?
rvm, rbenv, chruby ?

try adding the following file **.ruby-version** in your project folder
in this file put the following line

> ruby-2.3.1

then change to your home (or any other folder) and change to project folder back again

and also make sure which ever ruby manager it is, it is loaded replacing the system defaults.

i might be help you more after your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `bundle update`. You might have the incorrect version in your `Gemfile.lock` that `bundle install` is trying to follow.

Comment: The `bundle update` gives me a `Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.0`

Comment: Can you take a look at Gemfile to see if maybe `ruby` entry is duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems about version of `ruby` last time.

Case1, you should check your `Gemfile`, if your `Gemfile` have this line:

`ruby '2.0.0'`, you should change to `ruby '2.3.0'`, then it will work as well.

Case2, if you tried to do case1, and it doesn't work, you check file `.ruby-version` in your `folder project`. If it present, you only change:

`2.0.0` to `2.3.0`  and i think it will work as well.